# An uncountable collection of groups with no nontrivial homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

There are pairs of nontrivial groups having no nontrivial homomorphisms between them, for instance $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. (I can think of at least one proof, using Lagrange's theorem.)

With that example, it is easy to form at least one *countable collection* of groups such that no two groups exhibit nontrivial homomorphisms, namely $\{ \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\}_{p \text{ prime}}$.

> What is an example of an *uncountable* collection of distinct groups containing no two groups with nontrivial homomorphisms between each other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*For brevity I'll use the term "non-homomorphic" to refer to any family of groups no two of which admit a nontrivial homomorphism.*

---

For $A$ a set of primes, consider the subgroup $$G_A:=\{{z\over p_1\cdot ...\cdot p_n}: p_i\in A, z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ of $(\mathbb{Q};+)$ *(yes, this can be written more simply, but there's a method to my madness)*. The key point is that if $A\not\subseteq B$ then there is no homomorphism from $G_A$ to $G_B$, since if $p\in A\setminus B$ then the only element of $G_B$ which is "divisible by $p$" is $0$ but every element of $G_A$ is "divisible by $p$."

Now to get an uncountable non-homomorphic family of groups we just need a family $\{A_i:i\in I\}$ of uncountably many sets of primes, no two distinct elements of which are $\subseteq$-comparable. This is a fun exercise, and in fact we can get such a set of size $2^{\aleph_0}$:

> Fixing a bijection $$b: \mathbb{Q}\times\{0,1\}\rightarrow\mathsf{Primes},$$ for each real $r$ let $$A(r)=\{b(q, 0): q\in\mathbb{Q}, q<r\}\cup\{b(q,1): q\in\mathbb{Q}, q\ge r\}.$$ It's easy to check that if $r\not=s$ then $A(r)\not\subseteq A(s)$ and conversely: think about a rational $q$ between $r$ and $s$, and consider $b(q,0)$ vs. $b(q,1)$.

It's a cute further exercise (albeit one unrelated to the OP) to construct a size-continuum family $\mathcal{F}$ of natural numbers which are *pairwise almost disjoint*, that is, such that for any distinct $X,Y\in\mathcal{F}$ the intersection $X\cap Y$ is finite.

---

Note that the above idea is **completely useless** for getting even larger non-homomorphic sets of groups: it won't, for example, help us find such a set of size $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Interestingly, there's an odd "argument from authority" that any argument which builds arbitrary-cardinality non-homomorphic sets must be pretty complicated. It's due to the as-yet-seeming consistency of the following set-theoretic hypothesis:

> **(Vopenka's principle)** Given any proper class of structures of the same type *(e.g. groups)*, there is an elementary embedding between a pair of distinct structures in the class.

The [precise definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence#Elementary_substructures_and_elementary_extensions) of "elementary embedding" is a bit complicated, but all we need here is this: that all elementary embeddings are *injective homomorphisms* (in fact they're a lot more than that). So a fortiori, any non-homomorphic proper class of groups would be a counterexample to $\mathsf{VP}$. It's separately worth noting that $\mathsf{VP}$ is incredibly robust to modifications of the notion of elementary embedding; see e.g. the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138870/vop%C4%9Bnkas-principle-for-non-first-order-logics).

This roughly means that, unless $\mathsf{VP}$ is in fact inconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (which would be a **huge** result), there is no single way to construct a family of groups avoiding homomorphisms between them which can "go on forever" (= produce a proper class). For example, if I have a way of constructing a non-homomorphic family of groups of size $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, either I have to secretly be using some additional set-theoretic assumptions (which contradict $\mathsf{VP}$) or there has to be some "obstacle" to further enlarging that family to arbitrary sizes.

Amusingly, [Vopenka originally introduced his principle as a joke](https://mathoverflow.net/a/259943/8133)!

Comment: What is $D(r)$?

Comment: From the following line it looks like $D(r)$ is a Dedekind cut corresponding to the real number $r$.  You could also use unit disks centered at $r$ (and the $\{0, 1\}$ factor would be unnecessary in this case).

Comment: @LeeMosher Whoops, multiple-edit typo; fixed!

Comment: An overdue comment: this is a great answer that gave me much more than I was bargaining for when I asked this question. I was mainly hoping to see an example of an uncountable collection of distinct, non-isomorphic groups (I could not even think of one.) I had never heard (nor expected to hear of something like) Vopenka’s principle.